# Why does successive loadings of scenes take a very long time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene-manager

I have a simple 2D top-down adventure game.
There's a main level scene with houses.
The player can enter the house and when doing so it deletes the main scene and loads the house scene.
Respectively, when leaving the house, the player will load back the main scene.

The first few times of going back and forth between the house there is no problems.
However, after loading the scene's back & forth multiple times, it takes 20 seconds or more to load between scenes.

How can this happen?

For each house, I have a door that has a public variable of the name of the Scene to be loaded.

This gets passed into a function that loads the scene

**Code:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Transport : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject hero;
    private Transform heroTransform;
    private BoxCollider2D heroCollider;
    private ButtonPress interactButton;
    private PlayerMovement heroScript;

    public string sceneName;
    public int doorId;
    public bool isEnter;
    public bool isLoading;

    public void Start()
    {
        isLoading = false;
        hero = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        heroScript = hero.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        heroTransform = hero.transform;
        heroCollider = hero.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

        interactButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("InteractButton").GetComponent<ButtonPress>();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (heroCollider.IsTouching(this.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>())) {
            //Debug.Log("They are touching");
            if (interactButton.buttonPressed)
            {
                if(sceneName.Equals(""))
                {
                    // Do nothing...
                }
                else 
                {
                    // Only set return position if you are entering a door
                    if (isEnter)
                    {
                        heroScript.usedEnterDoor = true;
                        heroScript.setReturnPosition(heroTransform);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        heroScript.usedEnterDoor = false;
                    }

                    if(isLoading == false)
                    {
                        //SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                        Debug.Log("Loading next scene...");
                        StartCoroutine(LoadYourAsyncScene(this.sceneName));
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        isLoading = false;
    }


    IEnumerator LoadYourAsyncScene(string sceneName)
    {
        AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);

        while(!asyncLoad.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }


}
```

The profiler showing the performance drop when scenes become slow to load is shown below:

Profiler:
[image]

Profiler Deep Dive:
[image]

Being a bit more careful on where I place the cursor... I see there is a huge use of "GameObject.Activate" 81,920 calls with 3 GB of garbage collection.

[image]

Comment: Use profiler to find out ?

Comment: I added the profiler above... not sure what to do though. It mentions the RenderPipeline Manager is 6.8% and the rest of the items were 0%...

Does this provide any insight to what could be wrong?

Comment: do you see peak , check that

Comment: check the highest point , found out what function called

Comment: It looks like GC.MarkDependencies is the big peak. Something to do with garbage collection.... Added the image with the peak breakdown.

Comment: I google it "GC.MarkDependencies" , it's look like too many asseet to used. maybe you can use objectpool to save object , not create anything.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think I used that many objects...
Found this link too:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-avoid-gc-markdependencies.340906/

It mentions unloading the scene and also using Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
However, it doesn't seem to resolve it for me.

Odd it works fine then progressively gets worse. First load / unload is fine... only after doing it multiple times.

Comment: maybe memory leak ? not release clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Thanks @TimChang for your help troubleshooting / on using the profiler tool. I had a button that was being set to active / inactive. It was being called thousands of times.